# Swift: String from float without rounding the values

Tags: ios, swift

1. It is recommended to round the decimals but i am facing an scenario where i just need to cut down the precision.
2. Output: 15.96 to 16.0
3. Desired output: 15.96 to 15.9

Codes:

```
var value: AnyObject = dict.valueForKey("XXX")!
  var stringVal = NSString(format:"%.1f", value.floatValue)
```

I thought this will be simple but found tricky. Your thoughts on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to use the rounded number in future math operations, you can use the following function:

```
func roundToPlaces(_ value: Double, places: Int, rule: FloatingPointRoundingRule = .toNearestOrAwayFromZero) -> Double {
    let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
    return (value * divisor).rounded(rule) / divisor
}
```

You can then call it with

```
var value: AnyObject = dict.valueForKey("XXX")!
var rounded = roundToPlaces(value.doubleValue, places: 1, rule: .down)
var stringVal = "\(rounded)"
```

What this actually did was the following:

```
15.96 * 10.0 = 159.6
floor(159.6) = 159.0
159.0 / 10.0 = 15.9
```

---

Caveat:  This **won't** help in situations where you're using *scientific* precision, i.e.

```
1.49850e0 --> 1.4e0 // (5 places --> 1 place)
1.39e10 --> 1.3e10 // (3 places --> 1 place)
```

It will treat all numbers as `e0`

---

**[update 2018-08-09]**
Since it seems like my answer is getting some views, I would like to point out that rounding floating-point numbers by division can introduce errors because of how floating-point numbers are stored in memory. as user @mattt has pointed out elsewhere:

```
floor(1.5679999 * 1000) / 1000 == 1.5669999999999999
```

*(if you want to get your math on, [this paper](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a great primer on numbers and computers)*

If you need that level of precision, use fixed-point numbers instead. Swift provides the [`Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal) type for this purpose.

The important thing is to understand your problem.  If you're working with money or sensor data, you probably want Decimals.  If you're working with computer graphics, you can go with Floats.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. Will implement & update you shortly

Comment: they key is using `floor` instead of `round`

Comment: Working Great. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Use a `NSNumberFormatter` and configure its rounding mode accordingly:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.roundingMode = .RoundDown
let s = formatter.stringFromNumber(15.96)
// Result: s = "15.9"
```

Comment: Master Stroke. Thanks

Comment: @Chalfou one issue with this: 0.78 gives .7 which is correct but misses 0 before decimal point. Any thoughts on this. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can further configure the formatter. Add `formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 1; formatter.usesSignificantDigits = true`

Comment: Actually, just add this instead: `formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle`

Comment: Thanks @Chafou for your valuable inputs. You & Stephan simply came with awesome solutions. Might be thankful to Stackoverflow to give right to mark both answers accepted.

Comment: No worries! Just thought I'd point out an important comment Mattt (creator of NSHipster, AFNetworking/Alamofire etc) made on this same topic. Floating-point numbers can't always represent exact numbers, which defeats the purpose of solving this issue using floor. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544046/round-down-in-swift/31544141?noredirect=1#comment51086885_31544141

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
    var test : AnyObject = "15.96"
    var rounded_down = floorf(test.floatValue * 10) / 10;
    print(rounded_down)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated answer in Swift 5 based on @Clafou 's answer. You can use it as an extension to any data type. Example

```
extension Double {    
    func cutToDecimalPlace(_ decimalPlaces: Int) -> String{
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = decimalPlaces
        formatter.roundingMode = .down
        return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self)) ?? ""
    }
}
```

And you can call it like this

```
let priceValueString = "24.124"
let updatedPriceValue = priceValueString.doubleValue.cutToDecimalPlace(1)
```

Output will be
24.1