# Round down in swift

Tags: swift

I would like to round a Double to a certain number of decimals always rounding down.

**Example**

rounding to .00 => 1.5679999 to 1.56

rounding to .000 => 1.5679999 to 1.567

```
round(1.5679999 * 100) / 100 //returns 1.57
round(1.5679999 * 1000) / 1000 //returns 1.568
```

I want a Double not a concatenated String

Comment: For what purpose? If it's to display to the user, you should be using `NSNumberFormatter` instead. You should not rely on arbitrary floating point precision to format strings.

Comment: Because `NSNumberFormatter` will not change the underlying value just show a `String` to the user. #ifeellikemosesonthemountaintalkingtoyou.

Comment: More details: I am designing a custom number pad with a backspace button. When the user hits backspace they not only expect the digit to disappear from the screen but also from the value inputed. This is how I do it: `amount /= 10` `amount = floor(amount * 100) / 100` `refreshAmountLabel()`. Suggestions welcome!!

Comment: The described behavior is unexpected, except in the case of directly inputted numbers, in which case you're much, much better off representing each typed character as separate tokens and resolving to a number at the time of operation. With floating point numbers, there's no guarantee that multiplying and dividing by the same number yields exactly the same result, due to rounding error. (case in point: `floor(1.5679999 * 1000) / 1000 ` == 1.5669999999999999)

Comment: And FWIW, you can indeed get the displayed string back as a number from `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: So I recoded your way. It's much cleaner. Many thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just replace `round` with `floor`!

Comment: `floor(1.5679999 * 1000) / 1000 == 1.5669999999999999`. You can't divide and multiply a floating point to reliably change it's precision like that.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for pointing that out! PS -- I love you Mattt! :) Been wondering what you've been up to lately. Huge respect to you for all the awesome contributions you've made to the iOS community over the years.

Answer (score 50):

As of swift 3.0:

```
myDouble.rounded(.down)
```

Answer (score 21):

**SWIFT4+**

ways to round on different cases

```
var w = 6.5
w.round(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
// w == 7.0

// Equivalent to the C 'trunc' function:
var x = 6.5
x.round(.towardZero)
// x == 6.0

// Equivalent to the C 'ceil' function:
var y = 6.5
y.round(.up)
// y == 7.0

// Equivalent to the C 'floor' function:
var z = 6.5
z.round(.down)
// z == 6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 5.0

```
var x = 6.5
x.round(.nextDown)
// x == 6.0
```

Comment: no, it should be used like `x.nextDown.rounded(**your strategy**)`

Comment: Your code does not compile, with error _“Type 'FloatingPointRoundingRule' has no member 'nextDown'”_.

The `round(…)` method takes a `FloatingPointRoundingRule`, which is an enum with cases `.awayFromZero`, `.down`, `.toNearestOrAwayFromZero`, `.toNearestOrEven`, `.towardZero`, & `.up`.