# How to print float with only 2 digits without rounding in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point, rounding, precision

I have one float number initialized from a json server response like 65.788, 43.77, 89, 58.86985 …
I need print this with only two decimals digits. But without any round.

My problem is that while I format my float number to add only two digits, this format is applying an automatic round of the last digit.

```
let weight = 65.788
let string = String(format: "%.2f", weight). // ->  65.79
```

I’m getting 65.79 but I need get 65.78

How could get from the number of json response only two digits without rounding? Thanks!

Comment: Use a NumberFormatter and specify the roundingMode – this must have been asked and answered before ...

Comment: This might help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542199/swift-string-from-float-without-rounding-the-values

Comment: And between ceiling, floor, down, up, halfEven, halfDown, halfUp what is the RoundingMode to not apply a rounding?? @MartinR thanks!

Comment: @user3745888 There must be rounding. The number is represented in binary and you want decimal representation, it's not as simple as truncating some digits. You might get a decent solution by using `String(format: "%.2f", weight >= 0 ? weight - 0.005 : weight + 0.005)` but the real solution is to use `NumberFormatter` and choosing the rounding mode correctly (probably `.down`).

Comment: You are rounding. You are either rounding towards zero or rounding down, depending on what behaviour you want with negative numbers.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27705739.

Comment: If you will convert it into `Double` it will round anyway. You need to do it with `String` variable.

Answer (score 12):

Use NumberFormatter with `.roundingMode = .down`

```
    let nf = NumberFormatter()
    nf.roundingMode = .down

    // max of 2 decimal places (e.g. 1.23, 1.2, 1)
    nf.maximumFractionDigits = 2

    // starting with Strings
    ["65.788", "1.2", "1.9", "1"].forEach { s in
        let n = Float(s)
        let t = nf.string(for: n)
        print("[" + t! + "]")
    }

    // starting with Numbers
    [65.788, 1.2, 1.9, 1].forEach { n in
        let t = nf.string(for: n)
        print("[" + t! + "]")
    }

    // if you want exactly 2 decimal places (e.g. 1.23, 1.20, 1.00)
    nf.minimumFractionDigits = 2

    // starting with Strings
    ["65.788", "1.2", "1.9", "1"].forEach { s in
        let n = Float(s)
        let t = nf.string(for: n)
        print("[" + t! + "]")
    }

    // starting with Numbers
    [65.788, 1.2, 1.9, 1].forEach { n in
        let t = nf.string(for: n)
        print("[" + t! + "]")
    }
```

Output:

```
[65.78]
[1.2]
[1.9]
[1]
[65.78]
[1.2]
[1.9]
[1]
[65.78]
[1.20]
[1.90]
[1.00]
[65.78]
[1.20]
[1.90]
[1.00]
```

Obviously, you want to use error checking to make sure your original strings ***can*** be converted to numbers, etc...

Comment: set `nf.maximumFractionDigits = 2`